# your thoughts on implementing a 3D globe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

can you guys look at this screenshot - http://d.pr/IlEl

that's the intended design. Our user can rotate the globe left/right and on the globe they'd see which people are traveling to which place.

Someone suggested to use this library:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_earth.html

Unofortunately it runs in less than 2 fps... I was wondering if you guys can have any other suggestion or if its possible at all to do something like that in Javascript/HTML5 with an acceptable performance.

Comment: Really? Less than 2 fps? I'm not exactly using the newest computer on the market and I get a steady 61 fps.

Comment: It runs at 60 fps on my machine as well, but I guess the performances can get this awful with a lot of more or less smart phones (as well as old computers but these matter less). If the performance is too low with a 3D rendering I would consider using plain images instead, as you only want to navigate left/right on your globe (and if you slice it thinly enough, people won't even notice it isn't a 3D rendering).

Answer (score 0):

Have your looked at http://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe?

While it's not exactly what you need, the source is available, and you could easily modify it to provide the features you're looking for, with the great 3D performance that you want.

Comment: Ha ha, nice. 'Hack the Planet' on button rollover.

Comment: had to down mark this at it references the exact work described in the question.